# Empty nearables list estimote-sdk

Tags: android, bluetooth, estimote, beacon

I'm new to estimote sdk, using android studio. I got one beacon at home, and I want to work on it, get some flow with the sdk.
Using Xiaomi with android 4.4.4 api19

I got weird problem, my phone discovers nearable but the actual list of nearables is empty. Googled on it some time and no one had similar problem. It might be something really simple that i can't figure out just now. You got any idea? Got bluetooth enabled, only one beacon is close to me, on hackathon bluetooth crushed due to overload of beacons.

My code

```
package com.example.tom.test;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.estimote.sdk.Beacon;
import com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager;
import com.estimote.sdk.Nearable;
import com.estimote.sdk.Region;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private String scanId;
    private Nearable currentNearable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        beaconManager.setNearableListener(new BeaconManager.NearableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNearablesDiscovered(List<Nearable> listOfNearables) {
                Log.d(null, "nearable discovered");
                Log.d(null, "size of list is " + String.valueOf(listOfNearables.size()));
                int maxPower = 0;
                if (!listOfNearables.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.d(null, "in");
                    maxPower = listOfNearables.get(0).power.powerInDbm;
                    currentNearable = listOfNearables.get(0);
                    for (Nearable nearable : listOfNearables) {
                        if (maxPower < nearable.power.powerInDbm) {
                            maxPower = nearable.power.powerInDbm;
                            currentNearable = nearable;
                        }
                    }
                    displayCurrentNearableInfo();
            }
        }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                scanId = beaconManager.startNearableDiscovery();
            }
        });
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        beaconManager.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override protected void onStop() {
        beaconManager.stopNearableDiscovery(scanId);
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void displayCurrentNearableInfo() {
        if(currentNearable != null){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
                .append("temperature: ").append(currentNearable.temperature).append("\n")
                .append("contents: ").append(currentNearable.describeContents())
                .append("power: " ).append(currentNearable.power.powerInDbm);
        TextView infoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        infoText.setText(builder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Console

```
11-11 10:18:19.750    5940-6027/com.example.tom.test D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
11-11 10:18:19.750    5940-5952/com.example.tom.test D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
11-11 10:18:20.780    5940-6027/com.example.tom.test D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
11-11 10:18:20.820    5940-5940/com.example.tom.test D/﹕ nearable discovered
11-11 10:18:20.820    5940-5940/com.example.tom.test E/﹕ size of list is 0
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right hardware? "Nearables" are the smaller, sticker-like beacons. If you're using the rock-shaped ones, you need to discover them via ranging, and not nearables discovery.

Comment: I also dled official app and it also isn't discovered, it seems like battery is down